# Import single column text file using python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a text file that consists of numbers organized into a single column as follows:

```
0
0
23
23
52433
0
```

I am trying to read the data into an array and then graph it and I have the following script:

```
with open('r12c_24hr cement 1-11.TKA') as f:
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    e = zip(*(map(float, line.split()) for line in f))
    count = 0
    bins = []
    while count < 8192:
        bins.append(count)
        count += 1

    print len(bins)
    print len(e)
```

When I try to graph e vs bins I get an error that they are not the same length.  When I print the lengths bin is 8192 (the correct length) and e is of length 1.  When I print e and bins they have all the values. bins is formatted

```
[0,1,2]
```

but e is formatted

```
[(0,1,2)]
```

I suspect that is where the error is but cannot figure out how to import the values from my text file properly.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but why not do `bins = range(8192)` instead of messing around with `count`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue with setting up `e` is that, first you create a list of float numbers `*(map(float, line.split()) for line in f)` whose values are passed as positional arguments to `zip`. Given iterables as positional arguments, `zip` creates an iterable of `(iter1[0], iter2[0], ..., iterN[0]), (iter1[1], iter2[1], ..., iterN[1]), ...` when called `zip(iter1, iter2, ..., iterN)`. So, in your case, you are creating a list whose only element is a list of numbers - double nesting.

Simple `e = map(float, f)` would be sufficient. `map` takes in a function, and an iterable to apply the function over. Since a file `f` is an iterable that yields lines when iterated over and your lines consist of a single number, you can pass it directly.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  It seems my understanding of how the zip function works is lacking but this clears it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Each line will read in as a string with a newline at the end (excepting possibly the very last line). The `float()` function (actually a type) ignores extraneous whitespace, so you could try something like

```
e = [float(s) for s in f.readlines()]
```

in your loop. Your code does seem, however, to assume exactly 8,192 data values in the file. You might want instead to use

```
bins = list(range(len(e))
```

which will always give you the same number of bins and e values.